# How to insert the database information in biblatex-mla?

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

Here is the full citation information:

> Port, Larry. "Four Ways to Eliminate Procrastination." Law Practice:
>   The Business of Practicing Law 36.5 (2010): 18. Academic Search
>   Complete. EBSCO. Web. 8 Sept. 2011.

And here is my bibtex code:

```
@ARTICLE{why_not_procrastinate,
   AUTHOR  = {Larry Port},
   TITLE   = {Four Ways to Eliminate Procrastination},
   YEAR    = {2010},
   JOURNAL = {Law Practice: The Business of Practicing Law},
   VOLUME  = {36},
   NUMBER  = {5},
   PAGES   = {18},
   COPYRIGHT = {Academic Search Complete. EBSCO. Web. 8 Sept. 2011}
}
```

But here is my output:

> Port, Larry. “Four Ways to Eliminate Procrastination.” Law Practice:
>   The Business of Practicing Law 36.5 (2010): 18. Print.

So... Where does "Print." comes from, and how could I replace it with "Academic Search Complete. EBSCO. Web. 8 Sept. 2011."?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first part of your question, the `biblatex-mla` documentation has the answer:

> An entry with no deﬁned `howpublished` ﬁeld will default either to a
>   “Web” publication (if there’s a deﬁned url ﬁeld or eprint ﬁeld) or a
>   “Print” publication (if there’s not). To avoid `biblatex-mla` guessing
>   the publication medium, thereby printing nothing when the ﬁeld is
>   undeﬁned, deactivate the guessmedium option: `guessmedium=false`.

For the second part, there's no `copyright` field, so `biblatex` will ignore it. You can use one of the valid fields: `addendum` ,for example.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibtest.bib}
@ARTICLE{a,
   AUTHOR  = {Larry Port},
   TITLE   = {Four Ways to Eliminate Procrastination},
   YEAR    = {2010},
   JOURNAL = {Law Practice: The Business of Practicing Law},
   VOLUME  = {36},
   NUMBER  = {5},
   PAGES   = {18},
   addendum = {Academic Search Complete. EBSCO. Web. 8 Sept. 2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber,guessmedium=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtest.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will read the document next time. ;-P

Answer (score 2):

Rather than putting all that info in the addendum field, it's better to sort it out in respective fields:

```
@ARTICLE{a,  
  AUTHOR  = {Larry Port},  
  TITLE   = {Four Ways to Eliminate Procrastination},  
  YEAR    = {2010},  
  JOURNAL = {Law Practice: The Business of Practicing Law},  
  VOLUME  = {36},  
  NUMBER  = {5},  
  PAGES   = {18},  
  URL = {http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=a9h&AN=54459308&site=ehost-live},  
  EPRINT = {Academic Search Complete. EBSCO},  
  URLDATE = {2011-09-08},  
}
```

Then, of course, don't turn use package options to turn off the default AI (as defining the URL field will turn off "Print," add "Web" and the access date, and signal that the Eprint field should be acknowledged):

```
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

In this way, the phrase "Academic Search Complete. EBSCO." is italicized like it ought to be. As a bonus, it's also a clickable link to direct you to the URL.

...Err, on second thought, scratch what I just said. It's meant to work that way, and it does work that way for `eprinttype`s like Google Books and JSTOR, but not yet for anything so complex as "Academic Search Complete. EBSCO." Expect that to be coming up soon to a release near you.