# Multiple bibliography and MLA style

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I have to write my BA Thesis in the MLA Style and I tried different stuff such as
    [Biblatex and mla-paper making weird headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/biblatex-and-mla-paper-making-weird-headings) this.

The problem is I need to use two bibliographies, two .bib files. One for primary and the other one for secondary sources. How do I do that?

It also gives me the word "Print" at the end of a reference. I want to get rid of it.

Right now I'm this far (it has only one bibliography so far):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=35mm, right=35mm, bottom=25mm}                 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{underlin}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setcitestyle{notesep={  }}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\bibliography{prim}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cite[2]{
({ #1\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tempswa}}{ \nolinebreak[3] #2}{}})
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cite}
\pagestyle{headings}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\tableofcontents
\newpage                                       

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}

\begin{mla}{kim}{foo}{bar}{ha}{\today}{week}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.50}\normalsize

\cite[23]{maggie}
\end{mla}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with "Print" was explained and solved here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27917/how-to-insert-the-database-information-in-biblatex-mla/27919#27919

Comment: Something is not clear to me: do you need two bibliographical sections in your document, each one using a separate `.bib` database or you need only one bibliographical section, but using two separate `.bib` databases?

Answer (score 9):

In the following example I assume that you need two different bibliographycal sections in your documents: Primary Sources, and Secondary Sources; I also assume that you have two databases: `bibl1.bib` and `bibl2.bib`.

The idea is to use a `keyword` filter. In the following example I chose `primary`, and `secondary` as the words used to divide bibliographies.

To print the two bibliographies you can use the `keyword =` option for `\printbibliography`. For example, saying something like

```
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,...]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,...]
```

You also need to add a `keywords` field to each entry in the `bib` files indicating if each entry will be considered as "primary" or "secondary".

The code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibl1.bib}
@book{goossens93,
  keywords = {primary},
 author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach",
 title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
 year = "1993",
 publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
 address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@book{knuth84,
   keywords = {primary},
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {TeX}book",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibl2.bib}
@unpublished{patashnik88,
   keywords = {secondary},
   author = "Oren Patashnik",
   title = "Using {BibTeX}",
   note = "Documentation for general BibTeX users",
   month = jan,
   year = 1988
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla,guessmedium=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibl1.bib}
\addbibresource{bibl2.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth84}, \cite{goossens93}, \cite{patashnik88}

\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Secondary Sources}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the `guessmedium=false` option to avoid `biblatex-mla` guessing the publication medium, thereby avoiding printing "Print" (or "Web") when the field `howpublished` is undefined,

Answer (score 3):

Multiple `bib` files can be distinguished using the `label` option for `\addbibresource`. We can generate the primary and secondary bibliographies in two separate `refsection`s, where `\printbibliography` is limited to works cited via a `category`. This approach is demonstrated in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,showmedium=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibheading{primary}{\newpage\centering Primary Works Cited}
\defbibheading{secondary}{\newpage\centering Secondary Works Cited}

% ----------
%
% Replace this part of the preamble with:
%
%   \addbibresource[label=primary]{<primary>.bib}
%   \addbibresource[label=secondary]{<secondary>.bib}
%
% where <primary> is your primary bib file name and
% <secondary> is your secondary bib file name
%
\addbibresource[label=primary]{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{adams,
  title = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author = {Douglas Adams},
  series = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year = {1980}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource[label=secondary]{\jobname.bib}
%
% ----------

\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{Kim}{Vahnenbruck}{Professor's name}{Course}{\today}{Paper title}

\autocites{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric}
\autocite[10--15]{adams}

\begin{refsection}[primary]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[category=cited,heading=primary]
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}[secondary]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[category=cited,heading=secondary]
\end{refsection}

\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

First page:

[image]

Primary bibliography:

[image]

Secondary bibliography:

[image]

In your code, the lines:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={  }}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cite[2]{({ #1\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tempswa}}{ \nolinebreak[3] #2}{}})}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cite}
```

should be omitted from your preamble. Both `natbib` and `cite` are incompatible with `biblatex`, but `biblatex`/`biblatex-mla` can be configured to emulate any of their features.