# Biblatex and multiple bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I got convinced to use `biblatex` and already have the first problem.
I have several `.bib`-files and one of them contains only entries which shall be listed in a second bibliography (or even better: a subcategory of the bibliography). It shall look as shown here:

> BIBLIOGRAPHY
>
> entries from bib-files 1,2,3 alphabetically ordered
>
> BIBLIOGRAPHY 2
>
> entries from bib-file 3

The entries do not have any special `types` or `keywords`, I don't want to add them manually to categories and I don't want to split the bibliography by chapters/sections/segments/whatever.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35279/biblatex-multiple-bibliographies-categorised-by-different-bib-files

Comment: yes, but that solution only works with biber. Is there any solution with bibtex?

Comment: @Jonas If the second bibliography follows the same sorting scheme as the first, you can distinguish between source files with the `label` option as done [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28869). If it should be sorted in the order of the source file (i.e. `sorting=none`), you'll have to use biber - bibtex can't cope with multiple sorting schemes.

Comment: @Jonas: No, all good tricks work only with biber. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @Ulrike: because biber is not working out-of-the-box and i don't have the time right now to try to get it working....

Comment: Well if you have a current system and biber is installed it shouldn't be difficult to get it working. Normally you only need to adapt a line in the configuration of your editor. And sometimes (mostly after updates) you need to delete the biber cache.