# Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'multibib'

Tags: biblatex, multibib

I am having a common problem of incompatible packages, but I have not found anyone having the same problem.

I am trying to use {multibib} package with biblatex:

```
\usepackage{multibib} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references,referencesSoftwares,referencesBooks}
```

But it returns:

```
Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'multibib' \begin{document}
```

- I have to use biblatex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho you don't need multibib because biblatex already includes this functionaility. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19328/140011) explains parts of it.

Im suspecting that you would like different sections for references, Software and books. \printbibliography excepts optional arguments, please also refer to section *3.7.2 The Bibliography* of the biblatex manual

So for your use case I would expect it to be like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28869/140011)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{ref}{Primary Works Cited}
\defbibheading{software}{Software Cited}
\defbibheading{books}{Books Cited}

\addbibresource[label=ref]{references}
\addbibresource[label=software]{referencesSoftwares}
\addbibresource[label=books]{referencesBooks}

\begin{document}

    \begin{refsection}[ref]
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[heading=ref]
    \end{refsection}

    \begin{refsection}[software]
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[heading=software]
    \end{refsection}

    \begin{refsection}[books]
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[heading=books]
    \end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, this is not precisely what I want, but your answer helps a lot! 
What I want is to make separate bibliography for few papers of which I am author (called for instance "My articles") and I would like for that bibliography to have custom numbering - for example not [1], [2],... but [P1], [P2], etc...if you have any tips I would be even more thankful!

Comment: That sounds interesting :-) But I think your question could benefit from something like an example? B/c I don't really get it.^^

Comment: Hello, I solved it in the meanwhile. For my second bibliography, I used ...\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=P,keyword=my,resetnumbers]..., that added prefix P, and also reset numbering to start from 1! :)